# Excel Remove duplicate values that has some spaces

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to remove the duplicates from an excel column.
I have tried to use the in build remove duplicate values function present in excel.

Initially I had the following data

```
 University of South Florida College of Medicine
 University of South Florida College of Medicine
 University of South Florida College of Medicine
 University of South Florida College of Medicine 
 University of South Florida Morsani College of Medicine
 University of South Florida Morsani College of Medicine 
 University of South Florida Morsani College of Medicine 
 University of South Florida Morsani College of Medicine 
 University of Tennessee College of Medicine  
 University of Tennessee College of Medicine
 University of Tennessee College of Medicine 
 University of Texas Medical Branch
 University of Texas Medical Branch 
 University of Texas Medical School
 University of Texas Medical School 
 University of Texas Medical School
```

Upon using the remove duplicates function I was still left behind few duplicates 
After further analysis I realized the second row has some extra space at the end

```
 University of South Florida College of Medicine
 University of South Florida College of Medicine 
 University of South Florida Morsani College of Medicine
 University of South Florida Morsani College of Medicine 
 University of Tennessee College of Medicine
 University of Tennessee College of Medicine 
 University of Texas Medical Branch
 University of Texas Medical Branch 
 University of Texas Medical School
 University of Texas Medical School
```

---

```
 University of Texas Medical SchoolNOSPACE
 University of Texas Medical School ONESPACE
```

How to remove the duplicates that has some extra space at the end ?

Comment: Trim off the fat, I mean the white space with https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php as a good starting point perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TRIM` first, which will remove any additional trailing (or leading) spaces from your source data.

So if your data starts in `A2`, write the following in `B2`:

`=TRIM(A2)`

and copy or drag that down in column `B` until you've covered all the data. For extra cleanliness you can now copy everything in `B`, then paste values, and remove column `A`. Then use `Remove Duplicates` on your new clean data.